# How to make rooms available?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a website providing the hotel booking service as well as tourism information. The question is that how to make rooms available after the period of their booking has expired ..... This is actually a website and I'm writing it in ASP.NET and the code behind is C#.NET. The backend used is SQL Server 2005. I just want to ask what could be the possible logic to make the room available after the customer that booked it checked out the hotel. I mean, this room is to be now made available for any other customer. Suppose, I booked room A on 1-1-2013 for three days. During these days, if any other customer wants to book this room, it should be locked and the customer should be prompted to book another room. So, in short, the room should be made available the day the customer checks out and also should be available to another customer.

Comment: have you, at least, tried something?

Comment: how does the hotel currently track empty/available rooms? chances are if they're automated at all - they already use some sort of database. if so, you'll need to hook into that somehow.

Comment: i dont find a logic !!! OOPS :(

Comment: Re-asking once closed question with the same text isn't very polite. Voting for close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hotel Room Availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163277/hotel-room-availability)

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't meant to be a resource where people build your entire application for you.  I would recommend hiring a consultant.

Comment: Yossarian , please help him  , don't rebuke....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an attribute for the tblRoom like IsAvailable with boolean data-type.

And then create a method for your customer in customer class :

```
void Customer::leave()
{
   //set tblRoom.IsAvailable = true;
}
```

Note : When customer , reserves it , you should use something like that :

```
void Customer::AcquireRoom(ref Customer c)
{
   Room room= new Room();
   room.IsAvailable =false;
   c.room =room;
   
}
```

Use should create your tables and your program classes like below :
[image]